# React js Passing props to a component

Tags: reactjs

Hello basically I need to pass some data to a component to be able to popular that component:

```
const Data = {
  name: "a",
  title: "b"
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Div className="App">
      <Card name={Data.name} title={Data.title} />
    </Div>
  );
}
```

my card componen The component I need to receive data:

```
const Card = ({ props }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <p>{props.title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

For some reason I am not getting these props on my card component

could someone help me with a solution to move props from a functional component to a functional component

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-swanson-syuln

Comment: you are trying to destructure the props to get the `props` property from it. But there is no `props` property given. Remove the `{` and `}` in your Card component arguments or use `{name, title}` and reference them directly in your JSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component declaration is wrong. You should only use brackets to destructure props, not for the entire props object.

```js
const Card = (props) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

just get rid of the curly braces around props in cards.js

```
import React from "react";

const Card = ( props ) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <p>{props.title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```